# UiComponent Ui Element Ui-select Not Properly Working

Tags: search, uicomponent, magento-2.1.3, autocomplete

i m trying to create form using ui-component.
i want to create element SELECT like Product attribute set.

[image]

This field is created in my module but the searching is not displaying like below

[image]

**uiComponent Form Element Field**

```
<field name="product_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Poduct</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">product_id</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Did I forgot to add Some js liabrary In  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this option from

```
<item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

to

```
<item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```